# How to identify the code line that causes error during runtime

Tags: debugging, breakpoints

I have a C++ code that runs 288 iterations 8 times, and it takes an hour to complete a set of 288 iterations. Sometimes the program crashes after the first 288 and sometimes after the sixth run out of total 8 runs.

I am wondering if there is a way to know where this code crashes instead of me waiting 8 hours only to see the program crashing. I can run it in debug mode, however debugger shows the program crashing at a point where it would not crash if ran in regular command prompt interface.

Any suggestions would be welcomed. I am tired of waiting for 8 hours without knowing what is causing these random crashes. Should I use breakpoints for lines that I suspect maybe causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what programing language and what features its hard to give more detailed information.

1).  Determine what causes the crash?  If it crashes in the same place each time with the same set of input data that its likely some condition of your input data.  You can record which iteration you are on using variables and than lookup your data and call that iteration first assuming each iteration is independent of each other.

2).  Your code is crashing different places with the same data than its likely something to do with how it processes data.  Example is it timing out when trying to read data from another machine, are you running out of memory?

3).  May be able to add some 'smarts' to your process to check for conditions that you would expect the code to crash in and catch them and report them.

Information that would help answer the question.
- What programming language / tools.
- Does your calculation call third party API's or only your own code?
- Does your calculation process data that comes from something you have to read, IE) database, file, etc.
- Are you handling the reading of this information so that if it fails to read you are notified and it handles it gracefully instead of just crashing?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very generic, but from what I understand and I've seen during 12 years of programming, I'd guess you have a programming language like C++. You're probably encountering a memory leak or buffer overflow and the crash may happen at any time and any place, just depending on the amount of RAM and/or multi threading timing.

If the C++ guess is correct I suggest having a look at [Application Verifier](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20028). Run <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and enter `appverif`. It might already be installed on your computer.

Add your application and check all items in the *Basics* group. Save the settings. Then run the program under your debugger. It'll likely crash much earlier, when the debugger detects the first memory leak.

[image: Settings on a sample program]

The Microsoft debugger [windbg](/questions/tagged/windbg) has a special command [`!avrf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/hardware/ff562138(v=vs.85).aspx) to work with Application Verifier, but you'll also get better results in other debuggers.